# Jenkins VSTest Runner not working as expected

Tags: jenkins, vstest.console.exe

Having problems get VSTest plugin to work in Jenkins.
So first this command line version works spot on so I know the paths etc are correct -

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" C:\Pelican\Debug\net6.0\Test.dll /TestCaseFilter:"SidebarMobile" /Logger:trx
```

So back to Jenkins Dashboard>Manage Jenkins>Tools we have
[image]

And in the job itself
[image]

So when I run the job I see this in console output even though the paths are correct

```
Path To VSTest.console.exe: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\
no files matching the pattern C:\Pelican\Debug\net6.0\Test.dll
Executing VSTest: cmd.exe /C C:\Users\jenkins\AppData\Local\Temp\vstest7467014175321632084.bat && exit %ERRORLEVEL%
[Pi Mobile Tests] $ cmd.exe /C C:\Users\jenkins\AppData\Local\Temp\vstest7467014175321632084.bat && exit %ERRORLEVEL%

C:\Users\jenkins\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Pi Mobile Tests>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\ /Tests:Sidebar /TestCaseFilter:"SidebarMobile" /UseVsixExtensions:false /Logger:trx 
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

So back to Jenkins Dashboard>Manage Jenkins>Tools we now have

```
C:\PROGRA~1\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\
```

I now see

```
Path To VSTest.console.exe: C:\PROGRA~1\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\
no files matching the pattern C:\Pelican\Debug\net6.0\Test.dll
Executing VSTest: cmd.exe /C C:\Users\jenkins\AppData\Local\Temp\vstest17161354381707712024.bat && exit %ERRORLEVEL%
[Pi Mobile Tests] $ cmd.exe /C C:\Users\jenkins\AppData\Local\Temp\vstest17161354381707712024.bat && exit %ERRORLEVEL%

C:\Users\jenkins\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Pi Mobile Tests>C:\PROGRA~1\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\ /Tests:Sidebar /TestCaseFilter:"SidebarMobile" /UseVsixExtensions:false /Logger:trx 
'C:\PROGRA~1\Microsoft' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Any solutions please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now using "Execute Windows batch command", works fine from there